# How do I setup a "rolling window"?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to figure out the way I can set up a rolling window for a variable.
The variable will record a number increasing # amount of times from the minute before.

My basic interval timer

```
var kp123 = Number('1');
var myInt = setInterval(function () {
  kp123 = 1;
}, 60000);
```

Whenever a specific command is sent, `kp123` gets increased by 1:
`kp123++;`

This variable may increase 20 times every second, or only 2-3 times every second.

Right now how the system is set up, it records the variable # every minute, however, the data gets reset when the interval timer reaches one minute.

Comment: What do you mean by rolling?

Comment: @user9993 rolling as in, the variable data collected from 60 seconds will be deleted, and the variable data from 1 second ago will be added.

Comment: After 60 seconds set the value to zero? Where's the problem exactly?

Comment: @user9993 I want to retain the data from the past minute of whenever kp123 is called.

Comment: so store it in another variable?

Comment: Are you looking for an array?

Comment: @user9993 I think thats how I would make it, but I do not know how I could make it so that the last second gets removed from the array and the latest second gets added to the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var kp123 = Number('1');
var kp123History = []; // The history of kp123 is stored in this variable each minute

var myInt = setInterval(function () {
  kp123History.push(kp123);
  kp123 = 1;

  console.log(kp123History); // You can see the results in the console each minute like this
}, 60000);
```

or if you only want the previous value, and not the full history, try this

```
var kp123 = Number('1');
var prevKp123 = null; // The previous value of kp123 is stored in this variable each minute

var myInt = setInterval(function () {
  prevKp123 = kp123;
  kp123 = 1;
}, 60000);
```

Comment: OP also didn't mention a maximum amount. As it stands if the code runs long enough it could end up consuming a huge amount of memory and being terminated by the browser. Perhaps it needs a cap.

Comment: That is true, but with a minute interval, it is negligible. (I estimated 4.2 MB after one full year.) OP, if you do worry about memory usage, you can do `kp123History = kp123History.slice(-100)` to keep the last 100 results.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like (per the comments) you want a rolling average ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average)). You don't really show enough of your code for me to give a specific answer to you, but in general, you can't deduce a rolling average from just averages, you'll need to know actual values and their timestamps. I.e. you can't summarize your data and throw away the timestmaps.

```js
class RollingAverage {
  constructor(windowMs = 1000) {
    this.windowMs_ = windowMs;
    this.values_ = [];
  }

  addValue(value = 1) {
    let time = Date.now();
    this.values_.push({value, time});
  }

  get average() {
    let now = Date.now();
    this.values_ = this.values_.filter(({time}) => now - time <= this.windowMs_ * 1000);
    return this.values_
            .map(({value}) => value)
            .reduce((a, b) => a + b)
        / this.values_.length;
  }
}

let test = async () => {
  let sleep = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

  let avg = new RollingAverage();
  avg.addValue(1);
  console.log(avg.average); // 1
  await sleep(600);
  console.log(avg.average); // 1
  avg.addValue(3);
  console.log(avg.average); // 2
  await sleep(600);
  console.log(avg.average); // 3
  avg.addValue(5);
  console.log(avg.average); // 4
}
test();
```

Comment: That is some pretty heavy code for someone who's only just learning about arrays...